# Sanity Rich text editor block options are showing up but are disabled and unable to use them

Tags: typescript, next.js, sanity

I'm currently working on a Next.js + Sanity Project. I'm having an issue with the type Block from Sanity. In a previous project it worked but in the current project (with the same setup), the block options do show up, but it's disabled. (Image attached for reference) and it's not getting saved either.

[image: rich text editor but the options are disabled]

Here's my `blockContent` schema:

```js
import { defineType, defineArrayMember } from 'sanity';

/**
 * This is the schema type for block content used in the post document type
 * Importing this type into the studio configuration's `schema` property
 * lets you reuse it in other document types with:
 *  {
 *    name: 'someName',
 *    title: 'Some title',
 *    type: 'blockContent'
 *  }
 */

export default defineType({
    title: 'Block Content',
    name: 'blockContent',
    type: 'array',
    of: [
        defineArrayMember({
            title: 'Block',
            type: 'block',
            // Styles let you define what blocks can be marked up as. The default
            // set corresponds with HTML tags, but you can set any title or value
            // you want, and decide how you want to deal with it where you want to
            // use your content.
            styles: [
                { title: 'Normal', value: 'normal' },
                { title: 'H1', value: 'h1' },
                { title: 'H2', value: 'h2' },
                { title: 'H3', value: 'h3' },
                { title: 'H4', value: 'h4' },
                { title: 'Quote', value: 'blockquote' },
            ],
            lists: [{ title: 'Bullet', value: 'bullet' }],
            // Marks let you mark up inline text in the Portable Text Editor
            marks: {
                // Decorators usually describe a single property – e.g. a typographic
                // preference or highlighting
                decorators: [
                    { title: 'Strong', value: 'strong' },
                    { title: 'Emphasis', value: 'em' },
                    { title: 'Underline', value: 'underline' },
                    { title: 'Strike', value: 'strike-through' },
                ],
                // Annotations can be any object structure – e.g. a link or a footnote.
                annotations: [
                    {
                        title: 'URL',
                        name: 'link',
                        type: 'object',
                        fields: [
                            {
                                title: 'URL',
                                name: 'href',
                                type: 'url',
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        }),
        // You can add additional types here. Note that you can't use
        // primitive types such as 'string' and 'number' in the same array
        // as a block type.
        defineArrayMember({
            type: 'image',
            options: { hotspot: true },
            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'alt',
                    type: 'string',
                    title: 'Alternative Text',
                },
            ],
        }),
    ],
});
```

and here's how I'm using it in the event schma

```js
        defineField({
            name: 'description',
            title: 'Event Description',
            description:
                'A detailed description of the event, providing in-depth information. This content will be shown on the individual event page.',
            type: 'blockContent',
        }),
```

I've tried using the right package versions and it's still not working. Can someone help me sort this out. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't spent much time with Sanity, and while I love everything about it, I must say it has tons of glitches and I wouldn't be surprised if that's just one of them.
Yesterday I was presenting my client Sanity CMS I've made and we were face-to-face, me with my laptop and the client with theirs. I spotted that in the block content editor, which basically has the same setup as yours, my client has only the styles dropdown available and all other tools are missing from the editor while mine was looking and functioning normally. I have no clue how to even report it as a bug.

Comment: Hey @Guest, agree with that. I've mentioned the same issue in the sanity slack community as well but haven't gotten any response there either :(. If I do get some fix I'll let you know about it, would appreciate it a ton if you could do the same! Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing @kunalkeshan. I also opened an issue on GitHub so let's see what happens.

Comment: Update: I just found out that VPNs, AVs, and AdBlockers can mess up Sanity Studio. One of my biggest issues (not this one) was resolved by stopping the AdBlocker from running on my site so hopefully this could help you with your issue as well.

Comment: Thanks for the update, appreciate it. Oddly, it worked for me after I deployed it and still face some issues when working locally. I checked by disabling VPN and adblockers, and even went as far as disabling extensions but to no avail. 

As long as it's working on the deployed site I have no issues with it.